# SetPermissions for file sharing on OneDrive / OneDrive For business?

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint-online

Can you advise??

I am trying to programmatically insert file permissions in OneDrive , OneDrive for business, SharePoint Online, not unlike how you can do it on Google Drive.

ie: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

I cannot locate a OneDrive API scope/method to use to insert file permissions? (in effect to programmatically share a file).  Does anyone happen to know if this is possible, and if so which scope/method to use? I assume its something such as SetPermission?

I am aware that you can get a link via the 'wl.skydrive' scope within OneDrive API although it is unclear as to whether there are any permissions added ?

Thank you in advance

James

Answer (score 1):

The closest analog is shared edit and shared read links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631815.aspx#get_links_to_files_and_folders

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a SharePoint app, you might want to try using the SPRoleAssignment class, which might also work for OneDrive for Business:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment(v=office.15).aspx

Basically, you create a group, add permissions level, and then assign that to an item.

You can also use the UpdateDocumentSharingInfo method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharing.documentsharingmanager.updatedocumentsharinginfo(v=office.15).aspx) from the DocumentSharingManager class to share *internal* files in OneDrive for Business.
Here’s how to make the call:

DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo(
                                                _ctx,
                                                _resourceURL,
                                                new List() { _newRoleAssignment },
                                                validateExistingPermissions: true,
                                                additiveMode: true,
                                                sendServerManagedNotification: false,
                                                customMessage: null,
                                                includeAnonymousLinksInNotification: false);
                                            _ctx.ExecuteQuery();